# Equivalence of norms how to prove this?

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

On $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ I have two norms 
\begin{align*}
N_1(f)&=|f(0)|+\|f'\|_{\infty}\\
N_2(f)&=\|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}.
\end{align*}

We have always that $N_1(f)\leq N_2(f)$ but what about the other inequality please?

And please how to see If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are equivalent to $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{\infty}$.

Thank you.

Comment: What space are these norms defined on?

Comment: $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ @zhw.

Comment: Thank you, you should put that in your question.

Comment: are you here @zhw. ??

Answer (score 4):

Hint for the first question: By the mean value theorem, $f(x) = f(0) + f(x)-f(0) = f(0) + f'(c_x)x.$

Hint for the second question: Consider the functions $x^n,n=1,2,\dots $

Comment: And what about the equivalence with $||.||_{\infty}$ ?

Comment: Is $N_1, N_2$ are equivalent with $||.||_{\infty}$

Comment: @Vrouvrou I've added to my answer.

Comment: $||x^n||_{\infty}=1$ and $N_2(x^n)=1+n$ right ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Yes that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t) dt$ hence
$\|f\|_\infty \le |f(0)| + \|f'\|_\infty$.

Hence $N_2(f) = \|f\|_\infty + \|f'\|_\infty \le |f(0)| + 2\|f'\|_\infty \le 2 N_1(f)$.

For the second part, take $f_n(t) = \sin (2 \pi nt)$. Clearly $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$, but 
$N_2(f_n) = 1+2\pi n$.

Comment: is there an other example ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Another example of what?

Comment: more simple than $\sin$

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Are you kidding me???

Comment: no , i juste hate $\sin,\cos,...$

Comment: You need to put that in the question :-). @zhw. has a simple answer. However, **you** need to do some work yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Summarising from the other answers: $N_1(f) \le N_2(f) \le 2N_1(f)$ for all $f$ , which makes $N_1$ and $N_2$ equivalent norms (which always induce strongly equivalent metrics). But the example of $f_n(x) = x^n$ shows that there is a sequence with bounded $||.||_\infty$-norm which is not bounded in $N_1$ or $N_2$. This shows that the induced metrics not strongly equivalent, and thus the norms are not equivalent.

(using the fact that if we have two norms $N_1, N_2$, their induced metrics $d_i(x,y) = N_i(x-y)$ are equivalent iff they are strongly equivalent iff the norms are equivalent (in the sense that $\exists C,D>0: \forall x: CN_1(x) \le N_2(x) \le DN_1(x)$). The latter will fail when $N_2(x)$ stays 1, while $CN_1(x)$ can grow indefinitely, e.g.)